# Does bot api support creation of native polls?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot, node-telegram-bot-api

I’m trying to have a bot that is part of a group conduct polls based on certain parameters it receives instead of the users of the group creating the polls themselves. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a bot can create and send Polls to anywhere in Telegram.

Referring to `python-telegram-bot`, this can be done with `context.bot.send_poll(chat_id, question, options)`

Check out these documentations of `sendPoll()`:

[Telegram Bot API Docs](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendpoll)

[python-telegram-bot Docs](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_poll)